# Drools Execution, get number of retracted

Tags: java, drools, business-rules, drools-guvnor

I'm trying to return the numbers of retracts that a drools session execution have.

I can obtain the number of executions:

```
...
final Command fireAllRulesCmd = CommandFactory.newFireAllRules("executed-rules");
cmds.add(fireAllRulesCmd);
...
session.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));
final Integer executedRules = (Integer) execute.getValue("executed-rules");
....
```

Are there a similar way to obtain all "retracted-rules"?

Thanks!!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `org.kie.api.event.kiebase.KieBaseEventListener`, and in method  `afterRuleRemoved` count the events:

```
class MyKieBaseEventListener implements KieBaseEventListener {
    private int removedRules;
    public void afterRuleRemoved(AfterRuleRemovedEvent event){
        removedRules++;
    }
    public int getRemovedRules(){
        return removedRules;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

You have to attach this listener to the KieBase.

```
kieBase.addEventListener( new MyKieBaseEventListener() );
```

Comment: I'm using the version 5.4.0.Final of drools, the KieBaseEventListener is the same that KnowledgeAgentEventListener? Thanks!!!

Comment: In 5.4 the names are KnowledgeBase... in `org.drools.event.knowledgebase`